# set input text based on selected value from asp:DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dropdown

I've a DropDownList and beside it an input text. The dropdown is populated from Database.

Utility.cs

```
public DataTable Get_Student_Billing_Type(DropDownList lb, int faculty)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@P_BILLING_FACULTY", SqlDbType.Int);
                param1.Value = faculty;
                dt = DbAccessHelper.ExecuteDataSet("P_GET_BILLING_TYPE", new SqlParameter[] { param1 }, true).Tables[0];
                if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        lb.Items.Add(new ListItem(row["BILLING_HEADING"].ToString(), row["BILLING_TYPE_ID"].ToString()));

                    }
                }
                return dt;

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                return null;
            }
        }
```

This DataTable dt has 3 columns `BILLING_HEADING, BILLING_TYPE_ID, BILLING_AMOUNT`

My requirement is when user selects a value i.e. BILLING_HEADING from the dropdown list its corresponding BILLING_AMOUNT should be shown in the input text beside it. I know I've to use `OnSelectedIndexChanged` but how to show the corresponding field value from DataTable on selected item.

asp page code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputType" class="col-md-2 control-label">Type</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_type" class="form-control input_text" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDL_type_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input_text" id="inputTypeAmount" placeholder="AMOUNT" readonly="true" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
</div>
```

aspx code

```
protected void GetType()
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DropDown().Get_Patient_Billing_Type(DDL_type, 1);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }

        protected void DDL_type_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
            // how to write logic so that the corresponding BILLING_AMOUNT show for selected BILLING_HEADING

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var selectedRow = dt.AsEnumerable()
                     .Where(row => row.Field<int>("BILLING_TYPE_ID") == Convert.ToInt32(DDL_type.SelectedValue)).FirstOrDefult();

yourTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Field<int>("BILLING_AMOUNT"));
```

Comment: getting error `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'` in the query, `.Where(row => row.Field<string>("BILLING_TYPE_ID") == DDL_type.SelectedValue).FirstOrDefult();` `BILLING_TYPE_ID` has datatype INT in the table.

Comment: @user4221591 I assumed that `BILLING_TYPE_ID` has datatype string. So I used `row.Field<string>("BILLING_TYPE_ID")`. I edited my answer .I changed `selectedRow.Field<int>("BILLING_AMOUNT")` too.